# How to fix two-way binding with form input and vuex in strict mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a computed property(*itemInCart*) in my component which fails to run, until i hot reload my webpack dev server.
Also, I am not able to change the quantity(*qty*) using the form input

I have followed the steps in the [vuex docs concerning 2-way binding with forms](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) but still have an issue with my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="FoodItemCard">
    <div class="card-header">
      <img :src="foodItem.imgSrc" alt="food-image">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="title">{{ foodItem.title }}</h3>
      <p class="desc">{{ foodItem.desc }}</p>
      <span class="price">GHS {{ foodItem.price }}</span>
      <div class="card-action-row">
        <div v-if="itemInCart" class="qty-row">
          <span class="qty-title">Quantity</span>
          <div class="qty-action-row">
            <input type="number" min="1" class="qty-input" v-model.trim.number="qty">
            <button class="remove-btn" @click="removeFromCart">&minus;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button v-else class="add-to-cart-btn" @click="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the computed and methods section of the

```
computed: {
    qty: {
      cache: false,
      get() {
        return this.cartItems[this.foodItem.id].qty
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$store.commit('setItemQuantity', this.foodItem.id, val)
      }
    },
    itemInCart: {
      cache: false,
      get() {
        if(this.cartItems) {
          if(this.cartItems[this.foodItem.id]) return true
          else return false
        }
        return false
      }
    },
    ...mapState({
      cartItems: state => state.cartItems
    })
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart() {
      this.$store.commit('addToCart', this.foodItem)
    },
    removeFromCart() {
      // console.log('hello');
      this.$store.commit('removeFromCart', this.foodItem.id)
    }
  }
```

EDIT: setItemQuantity vuex mutation

```
/**
     * 
     * @param {Object} state 
     * @param {Object} payload 
     *    object that holds the [id] and new quantity([qty]) to set
     */
    setItemQuantity(state, payload) {
      if(state.cartItems[payload.id] && typeof payload.qty === 'number') {
        state.cartItems[payload.id].qty = payload.qty
      }
    },
```

I expect the code to change the `input`'s value to the new value I type (ie: *qty*). It instead ignores what I type and sticks to its old value.
I also expect the *itemInCart* to recompute as soon as i add/remove the item to/from the cart, and not wait for my to hot reload the webpack dev server before recomputing

Comment: Show the code for mutation `setItemQuantity`, please

Comment: @acdcjunior added the mutation

Comment: So I just realised the computed actually runs and changes to true(when i click on 'Add To Cart') but the template does not re-render to reflect the change